# Aligning Right on Window Resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to align an HTML  element on the right even when the window is resized. I have tried using CSS

```
#goRight
{
    align:right;
}
```

along with `float:right: , text-align:right` but the problem is that when I decrease the size of the window horizontally the  element is cut out and eventually disappears, which is not what I want. Is there a way to keep the element aligned to the right of the active viewing screen?

```
     <div id="address" class="tab">
        Filter by:
        <hr />
        <div class="label">Choices:</div>       
        <div id="goRight">
        <select name="myselect" id="myselect" size="0">
            <option>Option1</option>
            <option>Option2</option>
            <option>Option3</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="listSeparator"></div>
     </div>
```

Comment: I think we would need a link or more comprehensive code samples to help.

Comment: I think another element / style breaks your right align style. Because just `float:right` is works http://jsfiddle.net/T5F83/

Comment: I've added the remaining code above

Comment: @arunes Can you please post this as a solution so I can accept it? This is in fact what was happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`float:right` is simply aligns a html element to right, even window size is changed, element will still right aligned.

In your case i think another element / style breaks your right align style. Because just `float:right` is works. Simple fiddle at: jsfiddle.net/T5F83

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to position the element absolutely and set it's right property like so:

```
#goRight
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: At the current moment this isn't working, I'm looking at my other styles to see if they affect this.